# How can i change theme (dark / light ) in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, themes, vuejs3, emit

I have a problem in VueJS. I coding a website and i want to add a sun icon. I want to change theme when click icon. You knows; if theme is dark do light and the exact opposite. I think emit() is not work. But I am not sure.
This is codes:

**Navbar.vue**

```
<script setup>
  import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'

  defineEmits(['toggle'])

</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
          <span>osman<span>beyhan</span></span>
        </a>
        <div class="iconsTwo">
          <i class="bi bi-sun-fill d-block d-lg-none" id="icon" @click="this.$emit('toggle')"></i>
          <i class="bi bi-list navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasMenu" aria-controls="offcanvasMenu"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasMenu" aria-labelledby="offcanvasMenuLabel">
          <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasMenuLabel">
              <a href="/">
                <span>osman<span>beyhan</span></span>
              </a>
            </h5>
            <i class="bi bi-x-lg btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="" href="/about">About Me</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="" href="/projects">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="" href="/contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <hr id="line">
            <ul class="nav-item  d-flex d-md-flex" id="icons">
              <li>
                <a class="" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/osmn_byhn/?hl=tr">
                  <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="" target="_blank"  href="https://github.com/osmn-byhn">
                  <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="" target="_blank"  href=" https://wa.me/905350217844">
                  <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="" target="_blank"  href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/osman-beyhan-12304b23a/">
                  <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <br>
              <li id="ayrac" class="d-none d-lg-block"> | </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bi bi-sun-fill d-none d-lg-block mysun" id="icon"></i>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import '/public/Navbar.scss';
  @import '/public/Theme.scss';

</style>
```

**App.vue**

```
<script setup>
  import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
  import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue'

  import { ref } from 'vue'
  var mode = ref('dark')
  function toggle() {
    if (mode === "dark") {
      mode = "light"
      console.log(mode)
    } else {
      mode = "dark"
      console.log(mode)

    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div class="app" :class="mode">
    <Navbar :mode="mode" @toggle="toggle" />
    <RouterView />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  @import '../public/App.scss';
  @import '../public/Theme.scss';

</style>
```

When i click sun icon; function is works but theme don't change:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOfpb.png)

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

In the `script setup` syntax, you shouldn't use `$this` when emitting something, instead you should handle it like this:

```html
<script setup>
  // more logic ...

  const emit = defineEmits(["toggle"]);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="emit('toggle', someData)">toggle theme</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then in the parent component:

```html
<script setup>
  const handleData = (param) => {
    console.log("data passed was ", param);
  }
</script>

<template>
  <MyComponent @toggle="handleData()">
    ...
  </MyComponent>
</template>
```

But also, you could just add the `dark` class to the body, and while it's outside the vue `app` instance, you could just handle the logic directly in the `Navbar` component and adding the class in vanilla javascript:

```html
<!-- Navbar component, without emit -->
<script setup>
  const toggle = () => {
    if(document.body.classList.contains("dark")){
      document.body.classList.remove("dark");
    }else{
      document.body.classList.add("dark");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello your i use your vanilla code example but this code works only Navbar.vue but I want to this should work for <Navbar /> and <RouterView /> tags. How i can do it.

Comment: You should put this code where you have your sun/moon icon, it will add a "dark" class on the body, which contains both the navbar and the router view, there should be no problem